# Instapy does not install

Tags: python, regex, instapy

When trying to install Instapy on a Mac, it runs fine until I get this error. It also brings up a call box saying `The "gcc" command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?` I click yes, the program runs for a little then says `Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update Server`. Might be something with trying to install regex in conjunction with Instapy. Please advise.

***Error code:***

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/ls/n78nsrps7g11kns59t2n659r0000gn/T/pip-install-zvp3cah2/regex/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/ls/n78nsrps7g11kns59t2n659r0000gn/T/pip-install-zvp3cah2/regex/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/ls/n78nsrps7g11kns59t2n659r0000gn/T/pip-record-gqcrl4uz/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/regex
         cwd: /private/var/folders/ls/n78nsrps7g11kns59t2n659r0000gn/T/pip-install-zvp3cah2/regex/
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/regex
    copying regex_3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/regex
    copying regex_3/regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/regex
    copying regex_3/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/regex
    copying regex_3/test_regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/regex
    running build_ext
    building 'regex._regex' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/regex_3
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c regex_3/_regex.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/regex_3/_regex.o
    xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/ls/n78nsrps7g11kns59t2n659r0000gn/T/pip-install-zvp3cah2/regex/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/ls/n78nsrps7g11kns59t2n659r0000gn/T/pip-install-zvp3cah2/regex/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/ls/n78nsrps7g11kns59t2n659r0000gn/T/pip-record-gqcrl4uz/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/regex Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to download xcode. That updates everything on the developer end. Tried re-installing Instapy and it went right through. Also got regex in there as well. Woo!